# How can I Store Datarow Values in 2d array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow drcount in dscount.Tables[0].Rows)
{  
   int strsample5 =drcount[0].ToString().Trim();
}
```

dscount is a dataset name and drcount is datarow name.datarow has values of dataset.I need to pass the values of datarow to a two dimensional array.How can I pass values to two dimensional array?

Comment: Please elaborate what you want to do. Your code won't even work since you're putting a string to an int and there's no arrays of any kind there at the moment.

Comment: How Can I  pass the values of drcount(datarow) to a two dimensional array?

Comment: Unfortunately repeating that sentence doesn't make us understand it any better. You will have to edit the question and add an example of the data you have, how you want it to be in that array, what kind of a 2D array it should be etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, But, am not sure about your data. here strsample5 is an integer array. I think Its better to use Dictionary or List.

```
    for (int i=0;i< dscount.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++ )
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dscount.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            strsample5[i][j] = Convert.ToInt32(dscount.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString());
        }
    }
```